# asp.net/VB: user control in repeater - catch click event of button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, click, repeater

i have a `User Control`.

In this user control I have a `Repeater`.

In this repeater I have again a `User Control`.

If I try to catch the `click event` of an `ImageButton` in this user control, I'm gettin nothing because the event has not been fired.

Is there a way to catch this event?

*some code:*

first user control:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Rpt" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <uc1:myUserControl id="myUserControl1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

in myUserControl

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="myUserControlBtn" runat="server" OnClientClick="thisEventIsFiring();" OnClick="btn_Click" Text="btn" />
```

This event isn't firing:

```
Protected Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn.Click

   ' I am not firing

End Sub
```

Also the following does not work because it returns nothing:

```
 If Request(btn.UniqueID) IsNot Nothing
   'check if Button was clicked
 End If
```

Comment: in user control u can handle events i think

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="myUserControlBtn" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Click" Text="btn" />
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not change anything

Comment: thisEventIsFiring is this javascript method return a boolean? and are you sure there is no validators which is failing the postback?

Comment: I'm working with the javascript event, so it returns a boolean.

Comment: if it returns false, then the event in the server side will not be triggered.